# computer crashes in regular intervals when painting in photoshop

Tags: windows-7, drivers, crash, adobe-photoshop

I'd be very thankful for any kind of hint or advice concerning the following problem:

My computer **crashes in regular intervals when I paint in photoshop** using my graphic tablet. At first it takes longer ( usually 20-60 min ) until it crashes. When I then restart and continue to work on the same file, the **intervals get shorter**. After 2, 3 crahes, it only takes 5 min till it crashes again. Sometimes, the file is corrupted after the restart.

By "crashing" I mean: The screen suddenly turns black. For some seconds, the comuter makes a sound like "trtrtrtrtrtrtrtrrrrr...". The sound stops. The fans are still on. I can press any key, nothing happens.

This **problem only occured after I've reinstalled my operating system**. I reinstalled from within Win-7, in the mode where the old data gets preserved in a Windows.old folder.
After reinstalling I had a tablet driver problem. There was a bug, so I installed the second oldest driver version, 6.16-5.

When I first painted for a while, the problem occured. I reinstalled the driver. No change. I reinstalled the newest driver, 6.16-7. No change ( aside from that the bug from before was still gone ).

What can I do? Any idea why this problem could occur?

**Relevant Information:**

OS: Win 7 64-bit
(Previous OS: Win 7 64-bit)
Photoshop CS5 64-bit
Tablet: Wacom Intuos 3
Tablet driver: 6.1.6-7

Comment: Does the "trtrtrtrtrtrtrtrrrrr..." sound come from the speakers or from the hardware itself?

Comment: I believe it's the hardware. Though I admit I'm not sure right now, I'll pay attention to that when it happens next.

Comment: Cool now I know how to spell the sound

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the symptoms of an overheating PC.  You may want to run a CPU/GPU/disk temperature monitor and see what's going on.

Comment: +1 Yep, I concur. Try taking the side of your computer off to improve airflow. If that helps look into cleaning the dust out of your machine... carefully!

Comment: You could also try pointing a room fan at the open case... Keep it far enough away that it doesn't risk touching anything.  If it helps then you have a heat issue and should take steps to clean the PC and replace/add internal fans.  If you move internal fans be sure to keep the airflow direction correct IN the front/side and OUT the back.